# How to rename a file by retaining first 6 characters of my file name and remove rest of the characters?

Tags: linux

I have file names like: Rv0012_gyrB.txt, Rv0001_Rv.txt
How to rename a file by retaining first 6 characters of my file name and remove rest of the characters?
My desired output should be:
Rv0012.txt and Rv0001.txt
Please let me know, how to do it using a script in Linux for multiple files.

Comment: Do you want to retain the first 6 characters really? Or do you want to split the filename at the underscore (_)?

Comment: @StephanM.G. Yeah, I  want to cut my filename at underscore, so that I'm left with first portion (i.e., first six characters) before underscore followed by .txt

Comment: Will it always be 6 characters? Or will this also be sometimes 8 or 9, etc?

Comment: sometimes, it is 7, 8 also, but most of them have 6 characters before underscore

Comment: Okay, I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in *; do
  filename=${file%_*}
  fileext=${file##*.}
  if [ "$fileext" = "$file" ]; then
    mv "$file $filename"
  else
    mv "$file $filename.$fileext"
  fi
done
```

This should do it, assuming you want to separate at the first occurence of underscore.

Comment: Few of my files do not have any file extension (i.e., Rv5235_dnaN ?) In such a case, what I should change in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep first **6** characters, then this:

```
for file in `ls | grep .txt`;
do
    extension="${file##*.}"
    filename="${file%.*}"
    filename=${filename:0:6}
    echo $filename.$extension
    mv $file $filename.$extension
done
```

If you want to get all characters before "_", then this will do the job

```
for file in `ls | grep .txt`;
do
    extension="${file##*.}"
    filename="${file%.*}"
    filename=`echo $filename | cut -d "_" -f1`
    echo $filename.$extension
    mv $file $filename.$extension
done
```

In case you have some files without extensions, try this

```
for file in `ls`;
do
    extension="${file##*.}"
    filename="${file%.*}"
    filename=`echo $filename | cut -d "_" -f1`
    if [ $file == $extension ] 
    then
        mv $file $filename
    else
        mv $file $filename.$extension
    fi
done
```

Comment: What about the files which do not have any extension, What should I replace in the above code?

Comment: @Sand see answer